# Usage of word かんじ (not 漢字, but same pronunciation)

Tags: meaning, word-requests, word-usage

I know `漢字` means chinese characters, but japanese people use word `かんじ` extensively.

I don't understand when and in which context word `かんじ` is used and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your question might reflect some confusion about the Japanese language.

There are multiple words pronounced カンジ in the Japanese language. If you type on your computer, you should see a drop-down with many of them (in fact not all possible words with that pronunciation in Japanese).

For the most part, each kanji way of writing カンジ pronunciation is a different word (a large percentage are names).

The most common word pronounced カンジ is 感じ which means a `feeling, sense, impression`. It's the noun form of the verb 感じる.

One use of this word is 「そんな感じ」 which is often used to say something is basically (but perhaps not exactly) correct or as a ぼかし表現 (hedging expression).

E.g.,

> その子と付き合っているのですか。
>
> ええ、そんな感じ。

A different word is 漢字 which as you know means Chinese characters.

Other words exist as well such as 幹事 which means the person or people responsible for an event or conference.

Comment: Great Explanation. I understood.